# how to parse json data in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

how to parse json data,i need to display each and every data inside a div element. I am using world weather online api service to access weather data

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="in"></input>
    <input type="hidden" id="keys" value="api"></input>
    <input type="hidden" value="json" id="format"></input>
    <button id="go">Search</button>
   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#go").click(function(){
                var apikey = $("#keys").val();
                var q = $("#in").val();
                var format = $("#format").val();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?key=' + apikey + '&q=' + q + '&format=' + format,
                    success: function(response) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        console.log(obj);
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example output for berlin:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?key=api&q=berlin&format=json`

```
{"coord":{"lon":13.41,"lat":52.52},"sys":{"message":0.0826,"country":"DE","sunrise":1433386009,"sunset":1433445756},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":290.628,"temp_min":290.628,"temp_max":290.628,"pressure":1037.43,"sea_level":1043.19,"grnd_level":1037.43,"humidity":81},"wind":{"speed":2.42,"deg":314.504},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1433424243,"id":2950159,"name":"Berlin","cod":200}
```

Comment: Where is `div` element and how does the data look like?

Comment: Try console.log(response) to see what that's returning and share it here, your issue isn't helped by the ajax call and people won't be able to help you from this code snippet, we'll need to know what you are trying to actually parse.

Comment: And what, where and how do you want to display it?

Comment: all i need is to extract the temperature value from json and dispaly it in a div(div not created in above code)

Answer (score 1):

Here, `JSON.parse(response)` will return an array. You can access the elements in the array either by keys or the indexes.

For example, `obj[0]` is the `'0'th` element in the array(or the response text)'

and

`obj.some_attribute_name` will access the element by the key.